# Perl6::Slurp of DATA

Tags: perl, fileslurp

could someone please post a reference example of Perl6::Slurp with the DATA filehandle?

```
use strict;
use Perl6::Slurp;

my $contents = slurp(*DATA);

__END__
line 1
line 2
```

fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reference to a typeglob is a suitable argument to `Perl6::Slurp::slurp`, as the [perldoc](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Slurp) demonstrates.

```
use Perl6::Slurp;

$hw = slurp \*DATA;
print $hw;

__DATA__
hello
world
```